# Erro em conexão com banco usando PDO

Tags: php, pdo

**Mensagem de erro:**

> **Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: Este host não é conhecido.**

**código**

```
    $db_name = 'db_name';
    $hostname = 'mysql.hostinger.com.br';
    $username = 'username';
    $password = 'password';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO atividade(titulo, descricao, data_atividade) VALUES(:titulo, :descricao, :data_atividade);";

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db_name', $username, $password);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }`
```

Deixei apenas o `$hostname` preenchido corretamente pois é nele que tá dando o erro.
Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço desde já!

Comment: Hostinger na versão free não faz conexões com banco de dados mysql; para isso tem que comprar um pacote de hospedagem

Comment: No cpanel da hostinger vá em ''MySQL Remoto'' e habilite o banco de dados, simples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basicamente esse nome de domínio não está acessível na rede publica. Se o código for hospedado no hostinger, basta colocar como localhost. Outra alternativa é colocar o endereço ip do servidor mysql (que é o mesmo ip da hospedagem).

Answer (score 2):

Na verdade o hostname está incorreto, para acessar via php externo (fora da localhost da hostinger) ou qualquer outra linguagem, você deve usar 'sql141.main-hosting.eu'

```
$db_host = "sql141.main-hosting.eu";
$db_user = "u265779999_meme";
$db_pass = "admin";
$db_name = "u265779999_teste";
$conexao = mysqli_connect("$db_host", "$db_user", "$db_pass", "$db_name");

if(mysqli_connect_errno($conexao)){
    $resultado = mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
}
```